# Pandas Group By and Sum , Header being removed

Tags: python, pandas

after I run the following code I seem to lose the headers of my dataframe. If i remove the below line, my headers exist.

`unifiedview = unifiedview.groupby(['key','MTM'])['MTM'].sum()`

When i use `to_csv` my excel has no headers.

ive tried :

`unifiedview = unifiedview.groupby(['key','MTM'], as_index = False)['MTM'].sum()`

`unifiedview = unifiedview.reset_index()`

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling
`unifiedview.groupby(['key','MTM'])['MTM']'`
will return a Pandas Series of only the 'MTM' column...

Therefore, the expression
`unifiedview.groupby(['key','MTM'])['MTM'].sum()` will return the sum of the GroupBy'd 'MTM' column...

`unifiedview.groupby(['key','MTM']).sum().reset_index()` should return the sum of all columns in unifiedview of the int or float dtype. 
Are you looking to preserve all columns from the original dataframe?

Also, you must place an aggregate function after the groupby clause...
`unifiedview.groupby(['key','MTM'])` must have a .count(), .sum(), .mean(), ... method to group your columns...

`unifiedview.groupby(['key','MTM']).sum()`

`unifiedview.groupby(['key','MTM']).count()`

`unifiedview.groupby(['key','MTM']).mean()`

Is this helping you get in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

What version of pandas are you using? If you check the documentation it states:

> Write out the column names. If a list of strings is given it is assumed to be aliases for the column names.
>
> Changed in version 0.24.0: Previously defaulted to False for Series

Since you are transforming your dataframe into a series object this might be the cause of your issue.

The documenation can be found here:

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html